# Backbone with Lodash instead of Underscore, and Browserify

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, browserify, lodash

I'm now trying to use Browserify, and I've got a problem with it.

I always use Backbone with Lodash instead of Underscore, so I wrote some shim scripts for Browserify:

`shims/lodash.js`:

```
'use strict';
/* global window,require,module */
require('../vendor/lodash.underscore-1.2.0');
module.exports = window._;
```

`shims/backbone.js`:

```
'use strict';
/* global window,require,module */
require('../vendor/backbone-1.0.0');
module.exports = window.Backbone;
```

`app.coffee`:

```
'use strict'
$ = require './shims/jquery'
_ = require './shims/underscore'
Backbone = require './shims/backbone'
```

I actually use `grunt-coffeeify` to build the Browserify modules, and it says an error below:

```
Running "coffeeify:source" (coffeeify) task
Warning: module "underscore" not found from "/Users/User/proj/src/js/vendor/backbone-1.0.0.js" Use --force to continue.
```

What should I change to work Backbone properly? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Somehow, it works with codes below:

`shims/lodash.js`:

```
'use strict';
/* global require,module */
module.exports = require('../vendor/lodash-1.2.0');
```

`shims/backbone.js`:

```
'use strict';
/* global window,require,module */
window.$ = require('./jquery');
window._ = require('./lodash');
module.exports = require('../vendor/backbone-1.0.0');
```

And comment out code below in `backbone-1.0.0.js`:

```
//if (!_ && (typeof require !== 'undefined')) _ = require('underscore');
```

This looks something wrong though...

Answer (score 3):

`b` is an instance of browserify.

```
b.require('lodash', {expose: 'underscore'});
```

for jQuery, look at my version on github : https://github.com/amiorin/jquery

Comment: This did not work for me. Could you expand on this technique?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any shims. All you need is correct alias in browserify task.

```
alias: ['./node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.underscore.js:underscore']
```

[Look at my example](https://gist.github.com/knpsck/a7c2ead6120c7dca152c)